# How to list all the pairs of numbers which fall under a group of range?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, data-science

Suppose I have dataframe df1 which includes two columns - A & B. Value of A represents the lower range and value of B represents the upper range.

```
  A     B
10.5  20.5
30.5  40.5
50.5  60.5
```

I've another dataframe which includes two columns - C & D containing a different range of numbers.

```
  C     D
12.34  15.90
13.68  19.13
33.5   35.60
35.12  38.76
50.6   59.1
```

Now I want to list all the pairs from df2 that fall under the groups (between the lower and upper range) in the df1.

Final output should be like this -

```
     Key                Values
(10.5, 20.5)  [(12.34, 15.90), (13.68, 19.13)]
(30.5, 40.5)  [(33.5, 35.60), (35.12, 38.76)]
(50.5, 60.5)  [(50.6, 59.1)]
```

The solution should be efficient as I have 5000 groups of range and 85000 numbers from different range.

Comment: How performance critical is this code supposed to be ? What do you mean by "efficient" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not blazing fast (~ 30 secs) on my computer) but could easily be accelerated with the `multiprocessing` package if you have multiple cores.

Generating data :

```
def get_fake(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(n * 2).reshape(-1, 2))
    df.loc[:, 1] += 1
    return df

df1 = get_fake(200)
df2 = get_fake(90000)
```

Then for the processing part :

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for index, start, stop in df1.itertuples():
    subdf = df2[(start < df2.iloc[:, 0]) & (df2.iloc[:, 1] < stop)]
    result[(start, stop)] += subdf.values.tolist()
```

Result is a dict but could easily be converted to a Series if necessary.

Comment: It produces the error `TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [0] of <class 'int'>`

Comment: @AbdullahAlImran corrected (changed `loc` to `iloc`). It worked with my fake data because columns were labelled with ints

Answer (score 2):

It will be easy if you use `interval index` i.e

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df['A'],df['B'])
keys = df.values.tolist()
values = df2.groupby(df.loc[idx.get_indexer(df2['C'])].index).apply(lambda x : x.values)

new_df = pd.DataFrame({'key': keys , 'value': values})

          key                            value
0  [10.5, 20.5]  [[12.34, 15.9], [13.68, 19.13]]
1  [30.5, 40.5]   [[33.5, 35.6], [35.12, 38.76]]
2  [50.5, 60.5]                   [[50.6, 59.1]]
```

Accessing data based on interval index will give you the keys so you can groupby and aggregate i.e

```
df.loc[idx.get_indexer(df2['C'])]
     A     B
0  10.5  20.5
0  10.5  20.5
1  30.5  40.5
1  30.5  40.5
2  50.5  60.5
```

Comment: Thank you. But it yields the error `ValueError: cannot handle non-unique indices`

Comment: @AbdullahAlImran tell me what should be the result if 'C' and 'D' fall under two different groups from 'A' and 'B'. ?

Comment: Then you can drop other groups and take just one group.

Comment: I'm not near my laptop now. Just drop the duplicates from columns 'A' and 'B', then the solution works fine.

Answer (score 2):

one solution is to use `apply` such as:

```
# first create your output DF with the keys from your df with A and B
df = pd.DataFrame({'Key':[(a,b) for a,b in df1.itertuples(index=False)]})
# define a function to find the range in df2 within the range from the Keys column
def find_range( key, df_2):
    mask = (key[0] <= df_2['C']) & (key[1] >= df_2['D'])
    return [(c,d) for c,d in df_2[mask].itertuples(index=False)]
#now create the column Values with apply
df['Values'] = df['Key'].apply(find_range, args=(df2,))
# output
            Key                           Values
0  (10.5, 20.5)  [(12.34, 15.9), (13.68, 19.13)]
1  (30.5, 40.5)                   [(33.5, 35.6)]
```

Note: I assume in your data the column C is always lower than D, if not, you have to change the mask in the function to check if both C and D are within key[0] and key[1]. Also, I did not have all your input, so Values for the row number 1 is different that what you show, but just an input difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Key'] = [(row['A'],row['B']) for idx,row in df1.iterrows()]
values_col_test = [(c1,c2) for c1,c2 in df2.itertuples(index=False)]
values_col = []

for i in range(0,len(values_col_test),2):
     try:
          values_col.append(list(values_col_test[i:i+2]))
     except:
          values_col.append(list(values_col_test[i]))

df['Value'] = values_col
print(df)
```

Output:

```
            Key                           Value
0  (10.5, 20.5)   [(2.34, 11.9), (3.68, 19.13)]
1  (30.5, 40.5)  [(33.5, 35.6), (35.12, 38.76)]
2  (50.5, 60.5)                  [(50.6, 59.1)]
```

Comment: It gives the error `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

Comment: @AbdullahAlImran Now i edited my answer to make it look more like the desired output. But how come it doesn't work for you?, it works fine for me, i use python 3.6.0, and pandas 0.19.2